# What is a concatenated term and in what contexts are they unexpected?

Tags: kframework

My main question is what an "unexpected concatenated term". I have some context for the error below though there seem to be a slew of other issues that might be confounding this one.

I have a term `foo` of sort `Map` and a term `bar` also of sort `Map`. `foo` takes a list of expressions and the goal is to place them all into a `Map`. To that end for each expression I call `bar` on it and concatenate. From the syntax of `Map` I believe it should be enough to then say `bar(exp) foo(exps)` to get the entire `Map`.

This compiles fine however when I try to run it as soon as I rewrite into `bar(exp) foo(exps)` I get a
`[Error] Critical: unexpected concatenated termfoo(...) while evaluating function _Map_`. I removed the expressions themselves for brevity.

I believe the issue may be with the `Map` union having a higher priority than my `foo` and `bar` so I tried assigning `bar` as a function though because `bar` is strict in its arguments this caused an error with sorts `KItem` and `Exp` being incompatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ALee we would need to see your code to be sure, but I think the confusion here is that you are trying to *union* two maps together, and K actually doesn't support map union.

We have the *constructor* `_Map_`, which lets you, for example, build the `Map` which looks like this: `"a" |-> 3   "b" |-> 4`. But you *cannot* take two arbitrary maps and use this constructor to put them together.

The reason for this is that the resulting term may not be well-defined (what if both maps define the same key, but have different values?).

Instead, if you want this behavior, you need to write your own map union operator, which makes a choice about what to do when there are overlapping keys in the two maps. This example prefers the keys from the second `Map` argument (over-writing the value of the first map if the same key exists there):

```
syntax Map ::= union ( Map , Map ) [function]

rule union(M, .Map) => M
rule union(M, K |-> V M') => union(M [ K <- V ], M')
```

Comment: Ah I see. I thought I had seen some of the tutorial code using something like `M1:Map M2:Map` but I think I need to examine that more carefully then. Thank you!